# Multiple erc20 transfer in one call

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am using transferFrom method to transfer erc20 token to multiple people in one call.

```
ERC20Upgradeable paymentToken = ERC20Upgradeable(tokenAddress);

// transfer 1
require(paymentToken.transferFrom(from, user1, price), "payment failed");

// transfer 2
require(paymentToken.transferFrom(from, user2, price), "payment failed");
```

My concern is what if transfer1 pass and transfer 2 failed. Will the transfer 1 be reverted ?

If not - How it should be properly handled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to take all money to contract first and then

there are two approaches

1. transfer money from contract to all users need to pay. This way there is atmost no chances of failure as money is being sent from the contract which has money.
2. Implement pull architecture - Basically store all money value in the contract and add some methods to get the balance and withdraw the balance.

If there is any other way - I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a bit overkill but i'd use low level calls to the tokenContract

```
   function payMultipleUsers(address tokenAddress, address[] memory users, uint256[] memory payments) external returns (address[] memory notPaid) {
        //this line is not required
        // ERC20Upgradeable paymentToken = ERC20Upgradeable(tokenAddress);

        require(users.length == payments.length, "Wrong parameters");
        
        //cant push or pull if the array is not in storage so i make a fixed size array with 
        //the max possible value and use an aux variable to handle indexes
        address[] notPaid = new address[](users.length); 
        uint auxIndex;
        
        //call the contract and store if the call wasn't successful
        for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            (bool paid,) = address(tokenAddress).call(
                abi.encodeWithSignature("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)", tokenAddress, users[i], payments[i])
            );
            if (!paid) {
                notPaid[auxIndex] = users[i];
                auxIndex++;
            }
        }
        //return all addresses that were not paid
        return notPaid;
    }
```

there are two things that you need to mind with this code,

1.- the smartcontract should be aproved to this so you'd probably have to make another function to make this contract operator of the tokens

2.- you need to verify the `"transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"` signature of the token contract

Source:
I get the idea from [call, delegate call and staticcall](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#members-of-addresses) section in the solidity documentation;

There might be better ways to do it but i think that this code does its work

***EDIT___EDIT___EDIT___EDIT***

Based on your comment I refactor my code and throw this longshot:

Rely on the ERC20 contract transferFrom

If the ERC20 contract is well formed, it should revert a transaction when someone calls its "transferFrom" and there are not enough funds in the payer's wallet; and since the execution of "payMultipleUsers" happens within the same Transaction,the state will be reverted and everyone who was paid will get refunded

You can safely loop as in my codesample below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Creator: @casareafer

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

interface ERC20Upgradeable {
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external;
}

contract example {
    function payMultipleUsers(address paymentToken,address theGuyWhoIsPayingEverything, address[] memory users, uint256[] memory payments) external  {
        require(users.length == payments.length, "Wrong parameters");
//seems that it was required after all ^.^
        ERC20Upgradeable contractToCall = ERC20Upgradeable(paymentToken);
        //Rely in the ERC20 contract revert
        for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
           contractToCall.transferFrom(theGuyWhoIsPayingEverything, users[i], payments[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another option that scratches my mind is that you could actually check the payer's balance of the token, then put a require like this in your contract:

```
require(totalToBePaid <= payerBalance, "Not enough $$ to pay bro");
```

Comment: I guess this code returns all address which were not paid, but what about refund ? I can refund those users after knowing which were not paid, but its not gas effective - also your code will become complex. Lots of cases.

Comment: Yes indeed it will return the addresses which were not paid; "About refund?" Since the transfers are not successful, there are no refunds to be made; My apologies but you need to explain more about the context;

Comment: when multiple erc20 transfer will happen - let's say when transfer1 passed and transfer 2 failed. We need to refund to transfer1 since anyway the method was  reverted.

Comment: in the code lines you typed says: 'require(paymentToken.transferFrom(from, user1, price), "payment failed");' ---> does From is a single guy who pays user1, user2, user....? i think your code and your comment do not completly match >.<. anyway I refactor my code, please look at my response